# Customize space between items in a NSToolbar

Tags: swift, macos, xcode-storyboard, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

In my MacOS app I have a `NSToolbar` with some toolbar items (`NSToolbarItem`) inside. I've been trying to change the space between the items by subclassing both `NSToolbar` and `NSToolbarItem`, but without success. Is there a way to customize this space?

Comment: Create your own toolbar with a bunch of `NSView` objects?

Comment: I'm looking for a cleaner and more direct solution at first, but if i enter in desperate mode I'll try that out.. thanks

Comment: Do you want to change the width of a space item?

Comment: there's no space item between two toolbar items, just the "natural" space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this i ended up inserting all the views of each toolbar item into a stack, so I could control the space between them with the `spacing` property of `NSStackView`. Then my toolbar has only the stack as a ToolbarItem.